# Open android intent from web page and get result

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent

Is it possible, with HTML/JavaScript, to call an Intent from a specific app and get it's return from within the page?

I know there are some commands I can put in href attribute, like `<a href=tel:555498765432/>` to execute phone specific functions, but what if i want to call an activity and get the return from it? Is there something like `<a href='intent:com.MyIntent'/>` ?

Comment: open yes, google for intent filters. Get return result, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your app by specific url when user navigate to it by mobile browser, to do it you have to create [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) for your Activity, e.g.: (assume your user should navigate to http://yourhost.com/startForValue?userid=1111)

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
<intent-filter>
<data
 android:host="yourhost.com"
 android:path="/startForValue"
 android:scheme="http" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT />
<category android:name="android.intent.action.BROWSABLE />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When the Activity will be started you will be able to get user id from parameters by

```
String parameters = getIntent().getData().getEncodedQuery();
```

When user done with necessary operations you can send ordinary HTTP request with required data and user identifier to link the data with the user. Ofcourse it's better to use some more secure auth mechanism like OAuth, but the idea will be the same.

Comment: What if i don't have control over the app? The application i want to call and get return is a 3rd party app from play store.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible in that case. If the 3rd party app has API you can try to publish your app which will works as bridge between the apps.